# Getting reminders for events with Microsoft Graph

Tags: office365

I'm trying to get reminders for events using Microsoft Graph.

I tried to request the URLs below :

GET https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/me/microsoft.graph.reminderView?startDateTime=2016-01-01T00:00:00&endDateTime=2016-01-31T23:59:59

GET https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/me/reminderView?startDateTime=2016-01-01T00:00:00&endDateTime=2016-01-31T23:59:59

For both I receive the same error message : "Unsupported segment type".

There's no problem if I try to do the same thing for calendarView :

GET https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/me/calendarView?startDateTime=2016-01-01T00:00:00&endDateTime=2016-01-31T23:59:59

Any idea ?

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

This is a bug in the Graph API. I tried the latest documentation for reminderView endpoint and still got an error. here is the github repo url for (Graph API):

https://github.com/OfficeDev/microsoft-graph-docs/blob/master/api-reference/v1.0/api/user_reminderview.md

Please submit an issue to be fixed here: https://github.com/OfficeDev/microsoft-graph-docs